# Using StreamReader with TCPSocket Client (C#)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpserver

I was wondering how I could use StreamReader for TCP Socket Server.

```
// server
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5125);

// server start
server.Start();
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
var reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
```

Currently, if the client sends something, it does not read or display anything, and on the other hand, I tried using the stream and storing it into a buffer `buffer = byte[1024]; stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` which displays incoming messages, but when the client disconnects `client.Connected` still thinks that there is connected and keeps looping endlessly and does not break out of the loop, even when tried with Try/Catch

Your help would be much appreciated! Thank you

PS: I'm very new to C#, so please excuse my ignorance in case this is a simple issue that I don't how to solve

Comment: Is the client sending a line break? `reader.ReadLine()` blocks until either `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` is received, or the client disconnects. If the client disconnects, `ReadLine()` returns `null`. Either way, you shouldn't be looping on `Connected` to begin with. Did you read the warnings in the [`Conected` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connected?view=net-6.0)? `Read()` will tell you if the socket is still connected or not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I love you, thank you so much. The reason I was looping on Connected is because I saw it on a popular tutorial, it was stupid of me not to go to documentation.

Comment: Side note: you are missing `using` on `client` and `reader`